# Xamarin Build issue in Visual Studio Team Services (was: Visual Studio Online)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Xamarin forms app with a Unit Test project. The unit tests used to build and run without any issues on my own instance of Team Services (VSO). My builds are failing right now, both on my own Team Services and on my organization's. I’m seeing errors like this in the output:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javac.exe -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -d obj\Release\android\bin\classes -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v6.0\mono.android.jar;obj\Release__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar;C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.0.1.3\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.0.1.jar;C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.0.1.3\embedded\classes.jar;C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Sup...
  obj\Release\android\src\android\support\design\R.java:10: cannot access java.lang.Object
  bad class file: java\lang\Object.class(java\lang:Object.class)
  class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
  Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
  public final class R {
               ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1933,3): Error : java\lang\Object.class(java\lang : Object.class)

I’m also a little confused, because the message I get from Team Services (copied below) refers to a bunch of missing assemblies that should have been installed via Nuget package restore.  I was able to build this solution on my own instance of Team Services a few months ago, but now it fails on both jimcrowley.visualstudio.com and office.visualstudio.com.

Are there any special requirements for Xamarin builds? The unit tests run methods in the PCL that rely on Microsoft.Identity.Client and Microsoft.Graph.

Summary
| Build
15 error(s), 2 warning(s) 
Build - 15 error(s), 2 warning(s) 
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\App.cs(4):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\App.cs(4,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(4):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(4,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Graph' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(9):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(9,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MailHelper.cs(9):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MailHelper.cs(9,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Graph' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(4):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(4,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Graph' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(5):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(5,17): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Identity' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(22):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(22,23): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GraphServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(18):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\AuthenticationHelper.cs(18,24): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GraphServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(21):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(21,16): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IPlatformParameters' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\App.cs(16):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\App.cs(16,23): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PublicClientApplication' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(22):starter\XamarinConnect\XamarinConnect\MainPage.xaml.cs(22,24): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GraphServiceClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have a NuGet installer step?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the default NuGet restore **\*.sln step. That step completes before the build fails, and the required packages appear to be getting installed. I do see this warning: 2016-10-27T16:39:50.9748648Z ##[warning]To connect to NuGet feeds hosted in your Team Services account/TFS project collection with NuGet 3.1 or below, edit your build definition to specify a path to a NuGet.config containing the package sources you wish to use.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the log, it uses jdk 1.6, it is not support SDK 52.0.

You can specify JDK version (JDK 8) in JDK Option of Build Xamarin.Android step.
[image]